# is there a situation where the `source` and the `processor` cannot be connected in the scdf dashboard？

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

Excuse me, is there a situation where the source and processor cannot be connected in the scdf dashboard? If so, what is the specific reason?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Not sure I understand what you meant by `cannot be connected`.

Comment: i mean, we cant create line between two apps using scdf dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The source (producer of the events) is expected to be connected to a consumer of the events which can be one of these:

- A sink
- A processor
- A named destination

So, to answer your question, there is no situation where a source cannot be connected to a processor as the processor is a consumer of events.

Comment: no matter the source create some kinds of message that cant be processed by sink?

Comment: If the messages can't be processed by sink, you can have filtering/routing logic to process only the needed messages either at the source or sink level.

Comment: i mean even such msg cant be processed by processor, it still can be received?